# Are "far better" and "way better" both in the same register?

Tags: formality

Are "**far** better" and "**way** better" both in the same [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)) and interchangeably used?

If not, what's the difference between them?

Comment: The difference is regional? As a speaker of BrE, I never say "way better", but "better", "much better", and "far better".

Comment: They both mean the same thing. *Way better* is more casual/ less formal.

Comment: The full OED defines this usage of adverbial ***way = very*** under definition 3 as ***slang** (originally U.S.). Extremely, very; really. Cf. well adv. 16b.* They don't say anything like that about ***far = very much***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real difference is that "way", as an adverb to emphasize degree or separation, is more informal than "far". They could both be used in a casual register, but "far" is perhaps more likely to be chosen by someone speaking formally.

This use of "way" was once slightly more common in US English than British English, but has increased in usage with recent generations and is very common now.